# Correct usage for common model method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im new to Laravel and trying to get my head around basic usage.

I have the following code in my controller at the moment related to terms/taxonomy models.

```
$taxonomy = Taxonomy::where('slug', '=', str_slug('brand'))->first();

if ( isset($taxonomy->id) ) {

  $term = $taxonomy->term()->firstOrCreate(array('slug' => str_slug($request->name)));

  $term->name = $request->name;

  $term->save();
}
```

I want to make it available to other controllers and not sure of the correct place.

I thought about placing it into the Taxonomy model under a method of 'addTerm' but the Taxonomy::where() doesnt feel like its right.

What would be the correct way to do this? Should it go in the Taxonomy model or in a helper file of methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view there isn't just one way of doing it.  I like to use the repository pattern and store sql related methods there so that I can reuse them across the application.

It's explained for example here https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/ and I found this article very helpful/interesting as well: http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services

Comment: Ive come across the Repository name a few times so will give these a look and see if I can get my head around it to use myself. Many thanks! Will give an update.

Answer (score 1):

When I tackled this issue for myself I went with helper classes. I wanted to keep my models focused on the data structure and to share certain activities across more than one controller.

The code below is an example for handling a mailing address. The use case is that several other entities would associate with one or more address(es). Ownership was managed through intermediate tables for many-to-many relationships.

(*This was my first exposure to the Repository Pattern and it looks very appealing. I will be exploring it further.)

#### app/Helpers/Models/Address.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Models;

use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as Validator;
use App\Models\Address as AddressModel;
use App\Exceptions\ValidatorException;

/**
 * Class Address
 *
 * @todo descriptive error messages
 * @package App\Helpers\Models
 */
class Address
{
    static $validation_rules = [
        'street_number' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'street_name' => 'string|max:255',
        'unit' => 'string|max:255',
        'city' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'state' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'postal_code' => 'required|string|max:10'
    ];

    static $validation_messages = [
        'street_number.required' => 'A street address is required.',
        'street_number.string' => 'A street address is required.',
        'street_number.max' => 'A street address is required.',
        'street_name.string' => 'A street address is required.',
        'street_name.max' => 'A street address is required.',
        'unit.string' => 'A street address is required.',
        'unit.max' => 'A street address is required.',
        'city.required' => 'A city is required.',
        'city.string' => 'A street address is required.',
        'city.max' => 'A street address is required.',
        'state.required' => 'A state is required.',
        'state.string' => 'A state is required.',
        'state.max' => 'A state is required.',
        'postal_code.required' => 'A zip code is required.',
        'postal_code.string' => 'A zip code is required.',
        'postal_code.max' => 'A zip code is required.'
    ];


    public static function store(array $data, array $options = array())
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, self::$validation_rules, self::$validation_messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidatorException($validator);
        }

        $address = new AddressModel();

        $address->fill($data);

        return $address;
    }

    public static function update(array $data, array $options = array())
    {
        // TODO: Implement update() method.
    }

    public static function destroy($id, array $options = array())
    {
        // TODO: Implement destroy() method.
    }
}
```

#### app/Exceptions/ValidatorException.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use \Exception;

class ValidatorException extends Exception
{
    protected $validator;

    // Redefine the exception so validator is captured
    public function __construct($validator, $message = null, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
        // some code
        $this->validator = $validator;

        if (!$message) {
            $message = join(' ', $validator->getMessageBag()->all());
        }

        // make sure everything is assigned properly
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function getValidator()
    {
        return $this->validator;
    }
}
```